# Independence of $\sigma-$fields

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. I have two questions:

1. Is is true that if random variable $X$ is independent from $\sigma-$fields $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{F}$, then $X$ is independent from $\sigma-$field $\sigma \left(\mathcal{A}\cup \mathcal{B}\right)$?

2. Let $N=\{Y\subset Z:P(Z)=0\}$. Is it true that $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup N)=\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\sigma(N))$?

Comment: What have you done and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your questions:

1. $X$ is said to be independet from $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{F}$ if the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X)$ generated by $X$ is independent from the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$. This means for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$, $C\in\sigma(X)$ the equation $P(A\cup C)=P(A)P(C)$ holds, likewise for $B\in\mathcal{B}$. If you can guarantee that $\mathcal{A}\cup \mathcal{B}$ is closed under finitely many intersections, then you only have to check that for all $M\in\mathcal{A}\cup \mathcal{B}$ and $C\in\sigma(X)$ the equation $P(M\cup C)=P(M)P(C)$ holds, which is trivial, as $M\in\mathcal{A}\cup \mathcal{B}$ implies $M\in\mathcal{A}\lor M\in\mathcal{B}$. Without the additional assumption, I think it is not true in general.
2. Frist we have to clearify the set $N:=\{Y\in\mathcal B|\exists Z\in\mathcal B: Y\subseteq Z\land P(Z)=0\}$. As $\mathcal{A}\cup N\subseteq \mathcal{A}\cup\sigma(N)$ and the $\sigma$-operator is isotone, we get $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup N)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\sigma(N))$. For the opposite direction: From isotonicity follows further $\sigma(N)\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup N)$, $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup N)$ and thus $\mathcal{A}\cup\sigma(N)\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup N)$. As the $\sigma$-operator creates the smalest $\sigma$-algebra containing the set applied on, $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\sigma(N))\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup N)$ follows.